# PHP actualizing data in MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I've got some problem with code that should work but I can't find any error :(

**my code:**

```
function editPriv($id, $new, $edit, $arch)
{
     $toWhat = 5;//($new+$edit+$arch);
     $query ="UPDATE `Logs` SET `privileges` = '".$toWhat."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";    
     mysql_query($query) or  die("".mysql_error());     
}
```

Don't know why But I am receiving `500 internal server error`.

Comment: did you check error log?

Comment: how can I do that? (eclipse doesn't show anything)

Comment: you mean 500 Internal Server Error..?

Comment: `500 internal server error` usually means a PHP fatal error. Check your webserver error log

Comment: I'm working on localhost

Comment: @PatLas even so, you must have some type of webserver running in order to run on localhost.

Comment: if 500 internal error then check your .htaccess file..

Comment: Comment this code and check that your page is loading properly or not. Because this code is correvt.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: without this everything is ok :(
I don't add that I include sql.php as:
include_once "../php/sql.php"; //im currently in www/admin/php/adm.php and file sql.php is in www/php/sql.php

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me also and the main reason is that the windows/unix file comparability. You must be loading the windows PHP file to Unix system. Just create a new file from cpanel and write the code there don't use the copy and paste option. If the error is not shown then requires certain tweaking with PHP, Kindly contact your server service provider to tweak PHP accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok, although you dont need the string concat in die(). If you dont want to go digging through logs like suggested, I'd recommend you enable display_errors in php.ini on your dev environment.

In short you'll want this in php.ini:

```
...
display_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE (or E_ALL | E_STRICT if you want notices included)
...
```

This guide sums up what you need to know about error reporting settings in php.ini:
[php-ini-error-settings](http://www.phpknowhow.com/configuration/php-ini-error-settings/)